# OpenCV cv2.matchTemplate crash: Unhandled exception at 0x74B5E4E4 in python.exe: 0xC0000005

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, template-matching

When I try to use the template matching method `TM_CCOEFF` of opencv package, my python crashed. However no error message was shown on my terminal. I can use the normed method `TM_CCOEFF_NOMRED` without any issue. I really need the implementation of `TM_CCOEFF`

The environment is Python2.7 from anaconda. OpenCV 2.4.11

The code is:

```
cv2.matchTemplate(img1, img2, eval('cv2.TM_CCOEFF'))
```

The error I got from Visual Studio debuger:

> Unhandled exception at 0x74B5E4E4 in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00090FE8.

Error report file:

-

-

6.1

7601 Service Pack 1

(0x4): Windows 7 Enterprise

Enterprise

7601.23313.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.151230-0600

1130

Multiprocessor Free

X64

1033

-

APPCRASH

python.exe

0.0.0.0

4f84a6c8

opencv_core249.dll

0.0.0.0

5408cb57

c0000005

00005253

-

6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4

1033

f8df

f8dfaee172ac09535f188b654ca18c90

6715

67151222e0799356f987ab35b4fd5e05

-

9829DFB7-2EA2-4836-A3C1-35C18A006A4F

Dell Inc.

OptiPlex 7010

A16

There is no other information I got from this crash.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You said you used OpenCV 2.4.11, but your crash report says 2.4.9...

Comment: @Miki Sorry I tried on two Machines, one is 2.7.3 and the other one is 2.7.9, they both gave me identical error. The core of opencv library is 2.4.11.

Answer (score 0):

you always should check for the resources:
c++ code:

```
Mat img; imread("im1.jpg",1);
if ( img.empty() )
{
     cerr << "whaa!" << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    result.create(result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1);

    cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);      // <-- add this
    cvtColor(templ, templ, CV_BGR2GRAY);  // <-- add this

    matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
```

This is C++ code but it worked for me.